# What is the formula of this linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to find the formula for $A(g_n)(x)$

where $A:L^1([a,b])\to L^1([a,b])$ is given by $A(f)(x) = \displaystyle\int_a^xf(t)~dt$
and $g_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is given by 
$$g_n(t)= \begin{cases}n & \text{if } t\in[a,a+\frac1n],\\ 0 & \text{if } t\in(a+\frac1n,b].\end{cases} $$

I've been unable to find a solution for this since I'm not sure how to interpret $g_n$ under the limits of integration.

Answer (score 1):

$A(g_n(x))=n(x-a), x \in [a,a+1/n]$

$=0, x \in (a+1/n,b]$